# How to enable dual monitors on Linux server with BMC?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have an ARM64 server based on Ampere Altra CPU. The mother board contains an Aspeed 2600 BMC chip, which provides the primary VGA controller (AST VGA controller) to the host, with D-SUB VGA connector on the chassis.

The AST VGA controller works fine (for example, with Ubuntu 20.04).

Now I added an AMD RX550 GPU to one of the PCIe slots of the server, expecting that I can get video output from the AMD card (via either HDMI or DP). But it seems that there is no display output from the AMD card (xrandr only shows one VGA devices), although Ubuntu 20.04 detects the AMD card and loaded amdgpu driver module successfully.

I am wondering, what prevents Ubuntu 20.04 (or kernel) from displaying video through the AMD card? Or what else I should do to enable it?